# Using a Submit Button to insert an entry into a MySQL database via PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, submit-button

I'm pretty new to PHP, so I'm not quite sure on what to do with this.

Basically I'm trying to insert an entry into my MySQL database, through a "submit" button in HTML. I can't seem to get this to work, is it possible?

```
    <?php
    include('db_connect.php');
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO chosenitems (ID, Name, Price) VALUES ('', '4-6 Days', '£75.00')";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    ?>
```

The INSERT works perfectly fine on its own, but I want it to be executed when the "submit" button is pressed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tobo.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: This is for a Computing A-Level Coursework Project mate, I'm not too fussed that I'm not using the most modern thing possible.

Comment: — There is a difference between "using the most modern thing possible" and "not using the thing that is marked 'this is £$%^!' and will be removed from PHP soon".

Answer (score 6):

Just set the `action` of the form to the URL of the script that performs the insert.

Note that since you are modifying a database, the request is probably [non-idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2) and you should use the POST method.

```
<form action="/path/to/your/script.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submt"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $SQL = "INSERT INTO chosenitems (ID, Name, Price) VALUES ('', '4-6 Days', '£75.00')";
     $result = mysql_query($SQL);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check button value is posted and can execute line of code in it.

```
<?php
    include('db_connect.php');
    if(isset($_REQUEST['SUBMIT_BUTTON_NAME']))
    {
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO chosenitems (ID, Name, Price) VALUES ('', '4-6 Days', '£75.00')";

        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    }
?>
```

Hope this will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I had for the submit details:

```
<form id = "submitForm" action="config/profile_save.php" method="post">

<button type="submit" class="button"  name="submit" value="submit">Save Profile</button></form>
```

Inside each input field on the page, I placed `form = "submitForm"`
I then changed the name too.(This is the super global variable later)

```
<input type="text" autofocus="true" class="custom_link_url_text" id="custom_link_url_text" 
name="custom_link_email" placeholder="Enter your public email address" spellcheck="false" 
style="width: 245px;" maxlength="75" form = "submitForm">
```

I was then able to capture the data on the next page using the name as POST variable.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $custom_link_email = $_POST['custom_link_email'];
}
```

Once I did that it was just a case of inserting data into the database.